# Need color codes for 2016 Ford Transit radio wiring harness

Tags: ford, audio, transit, wiring-diagram

I need the color codes for a 2016 Transit 250 radio wiring harness or a universal car radio wiring harness.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you looking for the stock (OEM) radio wiring colors? From which part to where? What radio option did it have in it?

Answer (score 1):

Most quality ICE suppliers Kenwood, Pioneer will supply the connector set to match vehicle and radio chosen.

These are usually quality items that match the existing manufacturer supplied plugs.

If someone has removed the original plug then working out which speaker wire is which means getting to the back of each speaker , or at least 3 out of 4... if the vehicle has a power amp system then that may be easier...